# WordPress permalinks object not found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I just installed a legacy WordPress 4.7 project on XAMPP 7.2.5 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4.

I found that I'm able to view the `*.php` files under `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/`. 
e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/wp-login.php`, and `http://127.0.0.1/index.php`.

However, all permalinks of the pages cannot be displayed.

[image]

When I visit one of the permalinks, I get an `Object not found!` error.

[image]

I've tried the solutions mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330039/wordpress-permalinks-404-not-found), but they don't work in my case.

What is necessary to make permalinks to be displayed correctly?

Here's my `/var/www/html/.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: rewrite module is on or not ?

Comment: I just turned `mod_rewrite` on by following the tutorials [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04). But the permalink still has problems.

Comment: After doing did you check for same using phpinfo() ?

Comment: I found that `mod_rewrite` is inside Loaded Modules in phpinfo(). Does this mean that rewrite module is turned on?

Comment: Just restart your apache ane give the file permission 777  or 655 and check

Comment: @AkshayShah Still not work :-(

Comment: Delete your .htacess and just reset the pemalinks from admin.

Comment: @AkshayShah What do you mean by "reset the permalinks"? I don't find any buttons that reset the configuration of permalinks.

Comment: I just deleted `.htaccess` file and let wordpress generate it for me. But permalinks still doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that the configuration of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` prevents `.htaccess` from working. After I change the config from `<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>` to `<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`. My problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently there are problems with permalinks settings.
You should try to change permalink settings according to [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)